# Parse XML File within Azure DataFlow

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I do have an XML file in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getProjectsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xxxxxxx">
         <return>
            <objects>
               <binaryProperties />
               <componentProperties />
               <dateTimeProperties>
                  <entry>
                     <key>plannedend</key>
                     <value xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00+01:00</value>
                  </entry>
               </dateTimeProperties>
               <doubleProperties>
                  <entry>
                     <key>quantity</key>
                     <value>0.0</value>
                  </entry>
               </doubleProperties>
               <durationProperties>
                  <entry>
                     <key>plannedduration</key>
                     <value>0.0</value>
                  </entry>
               </durationProperties>
               <integerProperties>
                  <entry>
                     <key>internalaccountingapproach</key>
                     <value>0</value>
                  </entry>
               </integerProperties>
               <listProperites />
               <stringProperties>
                  <entry>
                     <key>shortcut</key>
                     <value>NoC</value>
                  </entry>
                  <entry>
                     <key>name</key>
                     <value>Name of Customer</value>
                  </entry>
               </stringProperties>
               <XMLProperties />
            </objects>
         </return>
      </ns2:getProjectsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm currently struggling within Azure Data Flow to properly format / parse this XML file.
Any hints on how to do this the best way?
Would be really great if someone could give me a hint here

Comment: What do you want to do with it? If you read it as an XML source in ADF data flows, you should be able to process each tag as a column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the XML file has kind of a Key Value structure, i need to parse each key value couple to have the Key as an attribute name and the value as the according attribute value. The result should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERupe.png

Thanks a lot for your help